# Changing private folder name in AWS Amplify Storage

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm working on a serverless Reactjs application and using AWS Amplify for managing users and storing user uploaded files. I'm storing these uploads on an S3 in private mode. The folder name is, by default, the cognito identity id for the user. I was wondering if it is possible to change the folder name to be something like the username.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the identity id with username or any other thing in case of private mode.

You can get credentials and pass it to AWS.S3 constructor and upload files in folder where you want but you can not apply policy/restriction based on you own custom username base path.

```js
import { AWS } from "@aws-amplify/core/lib/Facet";

const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  ...credentials,
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: { Bucket: <your bucket name> }
});
      
      
s3.upload({
    Key: <your key>,
    Body: file,
    progressCallback: prgressCallback // if any
  })
  .promise()
  .then(res => {})
  .catch(err => {})
```

Comment: I have a similar question, how do I tell Storage.put to upload to a custom path on s3, inside the bucket we defined folders, I want to put files in one of the folders, ... can we do that with this amply plugin?